# Get name of a day from given day in specific format

Tags: python, calendar, python-datetime

I would like to find solution for converting date to day of the week (using Python). The day's format for example:

'28 Jan 2020' should return Tuesday.

I was looking for solution here, but couldn't find for this specific format. Does anybody can help with solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

```
 >>> from datetime import datetime
 >>> datetime.strptime("28 Jan 2020","%d %b %Y").strftime("%A")
'Tuesday'
```